# Is it possible to configure behaviour of NERDTreeToggle to use NERDTreeFind when opening?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

Is it possible to configure NERDTree so that :NERDTreeToggle acts like :NERDTreeFind if a buffer is not open (instead of the default :NERDTree) ?

Failing that, would it be possible to create a mapping/small script that could check the visibility of the NERDTree window and if open close it, if closed invoke NERDTreeFind ?
I looked at the NERDTree documentation to find if the visibility of the NERDTree window was open, but could not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=1` to close the tree when you select a file, and create a mapping for find:

```
nmap <leader>p :NERDTreeFind<CR>
```

Comment: That's perfect - your approach achieves the result I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

there is a function, which may help you to distinguish if the NERDTree is opened.

`nerdtree#isTreeOpen()`

you could test a little bit with `:echom nerdtree#isTreeOpen()` when you opened/closed the Nerdtree.

Answer (score 2):

I'm now learning to use Vim too and had the same desire to make NERDTreeToggle to use NERDTreeFind when opening. After some digging/googling, I had a go at writing a simple Vim script below, and it seems to work for me! :]

```
function! ToggleNERDTreeFind()
    if g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
        execute ':NERDTreeClose'
    else
        execute ':NERDTreeFind'
    endif
endfunction
```

And I just bound the above function to a shortcut key to use for both finding/closing NERDTree. Hope this helps.

```
nnoremap <leader>f :call ToggleNERDTreeFind()<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

small improvment of the function provided by thomaswhyyou which also works
if current buffer is empty:

```
function! ToggleNERDTreeFind()
    if g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
        execute ':NERDTreeClose'
    else
      if bufname('%') == ''
          execute ':NERDTree'
      else
          execute ':NERDTreeFind'
      endif
    endif
endfunction
```